# uwsgi closed connection without response

Tags: python, python-requests, uwsgi

I'm using django+uwsgi, the question happened when the workers work over 60 secs. I think it was a time-out question, so I set timeout both in client and server. Although uwsgi didn't kill workers over 60 secs any more, I still receive the error below.

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`

I checked uwsgi's log and I found something I can't understand, the client error receive at 60secs every time. However uwsgi's workers still working until it's done(at about 86secs) ,then uwsgi's log return nothing wrong.

uwsgi's log:

```
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 11)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 13, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 14, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 15)
[pid: 14|app: 0|req: 1/1] 172.17.0.1 () {36 vars in 481 bytes} [Fri Jul 14 05:05:52 2023] POST /segmentation/separate-pdf => generated 275914 bytes in 86902 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 161 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

my client code:

```
upload_res = requests.post(upload_url,
                           headers=headers,
                           data=pdf_page,
                           timeout=100000)
```

my uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
project=PandaOsra
uid=www-data
gid=www-data
base=/var/www/html
chdir=%(base)/%(project)
module=%(project).wsgi:application
master=True
processes=2
http=0.0.0.0:8000
buffer-size=65535
pidfile=/tmp/%(project)-master.pid
vacuum=true
max-requests=5000
daemonize=/var/www/html/%(project)-uwsgi.log
post-buffering=True
harakiri=600
mule-harakiri=600
reload-mercy=600
harakiri-verbose=True
enable-threads=True
wsgi-disable-file-wrapper=True
```

I have already set `requests` timeout and uwsgi's harakiri, I don't know why worker was still working, but `requests` told me the connection was closed. Did I miss something in uwsgi.ini? I have to mention that it only happens when workers working over 60 secs.